# How to save listview rows to textbox in multiple lines

Tags: listview, textbox, save

Ok So, I have a listview with 5 columns. I wrote the code below to get the text and subitems. Add them to a string using , as a separator. It works however my code saves all rows on one line in the textbox. I'm not sure where the issue is. Please Help

```
  Dim fileName As String="inventory.lst"
    Dim row As String = "", theChar As String = ","
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName)

    For Each item As ListViewItem In InvList.Items
        For Each subitem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
            row = row + subitem.Text + theChar
            'write to text file and remove last seperator
            objWriter.Write(row.TrimEnd(theChar))
        Next
    Next
    objWriter.Close()
```

Comment: set textbox property as multiline. and add new line character \n or @"<br />" when appending the string.

Comment: Currently its just inserting the row into a string. which does work. it just write all data to one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use vbcrlf to simulate enter between the 2 "next"

Comment: This should be comment